# How can I change animation of button when using QShortcut?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qshortcut

Before, I was used to using `button.clicked.connect(function)` to trigger a button and setting `qss` by `setStyleSheet()` (Eg: 
`QPushButton:pressed{background:#EAEAEA;}`). And the button will change background color when pressing button by clicking mouse and work as expected. However, Currently I'm using `QShortcut` to trigger the button (Eg: `QtCore.Qt.Key_Return`) but the button seems not to be affected by `qss`.

The code that I've used:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        Form.setStyleSheet(""
                        "#Form {\n"
                        "background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
                        "}\n"
                        "QPushButton:hover {\n"
                        "color: white;\n"
                        "background-color: rgb(255, 85, 127);\n"
                        "border-radius: 6px;\n"
                        "font-size:16px;\n"
                        "}\n"
                        "\n"
                        " QPushButton:pressed{\n"
                        "background:#EAEAEA;\n"
                        "color: black;\n"
                        "font-size:16px;\n"
                        "}")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 20, 351, 241))
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 100, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")

        # old (be affected by qss (QPushButton:pressed) when clicking mouse)
        # self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.send_message)

        # new (not to be affected by qss (QPushButton:pressed) when using Enter key)
        send_message_shortcut = QtWidgets.QShortcut(QtGui.QKeySequence(QtCore.Qt.Key_Return), Form)
        send_message_shortcut.activated.connect(self.send_message)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))

    def send_message(self):
        # do something here
        print("send message")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc Hey, I've provided my code. Please check again

Comment: The QShortcut is not triggering the button, it really has nothing to do with the button so your presumption is incorrect. How do you want the animation to manifest?

Comment: @eyllanesc Actually, I want when triggering button by using `Enter` key, the button will be changed background color for example

Comment: How long and at what color?

Comment: About 0.5s and pink.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198513/discussion-between-leminhnguyenhust-and-eyllanesc).

Comment: @eyllanesc Hey, You are still there ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seeing the "animation" because the button is not being pressed at all, but you can trigger it by using [`QAbstractButton.animateClick`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractbutton.html#animateClick):

```
send_message_shortcut.activated.connect(self.pushButton.animateClick)
```

This sets the button pressed (as in `setDown(True)`), then restores it after a default 100ms interval and sends both `released` and `clicked` signals respectively. If you want a different time interval, use a lambda (or do it in your own method) and set the argument in ms.

Comment: Thanks you for replying, I've tried your snippet of code, but the button seem not to be affected by `qss` ( Eg: the button will be changed background color as clicking left mouse, in my code above)

Comment: Here it works fine on Linux (I can't test on Windows right now). Have you tried setting a longer interval?

Comment: yes, I've tried `send_message_shortcut.activated.connect(lambda: self.pushButton.animateClick(1000))`, but it doesn't work as expected.

Comment: What OS, Python and PyQt versions are you using? Does `send_message_shortcut.activated.connect(lambda: self.pushButton.setDown(True))` do anything?

Comment: Python: 3.6.8, PyQt5 and OS: Windows. I've added your snippet of code, but it's do nothing when pressing `Enter`.

Comment: I just tried again with your original code on Windows implementation (but I've to say that it actually is PyQt4 and under Wine) using `self.pushButton.setDown(True)` within the send_message method, and it works perfectly. Are you sure you've not added something else? Can you try again using your posted code (exactly the same) and just add animateClick or even setDown at the end of the send_message method?

Comment: thanks you, it works well now, it's probaly my ommision.